# help solve inequality

Tags: inequality

help solve inequality:

$\sin 3x > \cos 3x$

Comment: Do you know $tang$?

Comment: I would divide both sides by $\cos 3x$. Then remember the definition of the tangent function ... Can you do that?

Comment: @MattiP.: I would abstain from dividing and look on a trigonometric circle where the sine exceeds the cosine.

Comment: @MattiP.: If you divide, you'll also have to remember to split into cases depending on whether $\cos 3x$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

On a full period, $$\sin\theta>\cos\theta$$ for $$\theta\in\left(\frac\pi4,\frac{5\pi}4\right).$$

---

You can also use

$$\sin\theta-\cos\theta\propto\sin\left(\theta-\frac\pi4\right).$$